# Using firebase just for Authentication w/ ASP.NET Core Web API backend

Tags: angular, firebase, asp.net-core, firebase-authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

My application uses an ASP.NET Core API backend and an Angular 2 front-end. Is there any reason it would be a bad idea to use Firebase just for Authentication and not for the actual database.

Comment: Not at all, I think you can do it that way.